# MVC Action History

Tags: model-view-controller, action

I have two actions that list out items.  Index() lists out all items and Filtered(string foo) filters the list of items based on foo.  When a user creates a new item, I want to be able to redirect them back to either Index() or Filtered(string foo) based on where they were before.

How can I do this, or rework my actions to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could modify your ActionResult to accept a string that contains the URL path the user comes from.

Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateFoo(Blah model, string returnUrl)
    {
        // Do something here
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl)) // As long as a return URL was passed
        {
            return Redirect(returnUrl); // Return them to this URL
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home"); // Otherwise Go Home
        }
   }
```

I don't have a ton of experience with ASP.NET MVC so there could be a better built in way to handle this. Googling for 'asp.net mvc redirect to requestor' might yield something more useful, that's essentially what you're wanting is to redirect back to the requesting route.

Comment: That's the only idea I had too, but I was hoping I was missing something or someone with some more experience knew of a better way around it.  Thanks for the post and if I don't figure anything else out I'll come back and mark this as the answer.

Comment: It does seem like this would be a common request and would be handled by the framework. Also not sure I like the use of the Negation before the isnullorempty call. I think i'd drop that and just reverse the if/else statements.